# Can I change the key to start/stop YouTube videos to "b"?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, youtube

My presenter sends <kbd>b</kbd>. I would like to use it as a simple remote control. YouTube supports space or <kbd>k</kbd> to start/stop videos. Can I change it?